# How to catch event inside uiscrollview on image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I have populated uiscrollview with images (code is bellow) but I don't know how to add some event to images inside. I want to double tap on image inside scrollview and get some event. Any direction how to achieve this?

```
arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *img;
    for (img in imgArray)
    {
        [arrayOfImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:img]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Array initialization complete...");

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 29);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    NSLog(@"Scroll View initialization setup complete...");

    UIImage *imageToAdd;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (imageToAdd in arrayOfImages)
    {
        UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToAdd];     

        temp.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 29, 29);
        x += 29;
        [scrollView addSubview:temp];

    }

    NSLog(@"Adding images to outlet complete...");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIImageView(s).

Look at [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1) for more info.

Comment: but according to iCodeBlog the uiimageview won't get the taps so you might have to take the uiimageview into another uiview .

Comment: I added now 
UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToAdd];  
  
  temp.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 29, 29);
  temp.userInteractionEnabled = YES;  
  x += 29;
  
  
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
  [temp addGestureRecognizer:tap];
  [tap release];

But I get: sigabrt error...
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DemoImageSlider2ViewController imageTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c28a00'

Comment: I changed handler method declaration to:
- (void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
 NSLog(@"ITEM >>> %@", [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:8]);
}
And it works, thanks :)

Comment: @hib It will get the taps. I'm doing this in my app. :)